# Why can't I have 2 waits together one after another?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

Ok so I am trying to click a checkbox the xpath is correct as I have tried it with WebDriverWait using Clickable.Click(); etc  But it only works if I scroll down the page and its visible.   I have found this scrollviewandclick code written in javascript alongside some selenium.  So Basically, if I want to scroll and click anything out of view I simply use

```
objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("YOUR Locator")));
```

As I was saying before it clicks if I move my mouse to the checkbox down the page using the following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("YOUR Locator"))).Click();
```

But I wish to change my javascript/selenium scrollviewandclick method to incorporate this click but it won't let me put 2 waits together.  Can someone suggest where I am going wrong.

Ths scrollviewandclick method is below:

```
public void ScrollInToViewAndClick(IWebElement element)
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            var elementList = new List<IWebElement>
            {
                element
            };

            var readonlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(elementList);
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(readonlyCollection));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element)).Click();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two waits in a row with no issues, I'm not sure what error you are getting. Seeing as how you seem to be newer to Selenium, let me explain a few things and make some suggestions:

1. You are converting a single `WebElement` into a collection for some reason? Presumably so that you can use `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`? You don't need to do this because there is a singular version of this wait method, `ElementIsVisible()`.
2. You don't need to wait for the element to be visible and then clickable. For an element to be clickable, it MUST be visible so waiting for just clickable is enough.
3. If you try to scroll to an element before it is visible you will get an error. So, wait until the element is clickable (visible), scroll to it, and then click it.

Keeping these three things in mind, I rewrote your code to the below.

```
public void ScrollInToViewAndClick(IWebElement element)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    element.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling .Click() on Wait.Until()
You should be using element.Click() after the second wait at worst.